# Is it possible to write a protocol in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, protocols

I want to write a protocol called [DSNP](https://github.com/ilhanyumer/DSNP) with Google App Engine so that it will be available on the internets, because I cannot make it run in a shared hosting. Is it possible to write the protocol with Java and then make it run in Google Apps Engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine and read the "Sandbox" section, which will explain in slightly more detail that the answer is No.